# How do I access a value in an object filled dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, object

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
import numpy as np

class Player():
  def __init__(self, health, maxHealth, baseDmg, dmg, name, weapons, items, isAlive, previousRoom, room):
    self.health = health
    self.maxHealth = maxHealth
    self.baseDmg = baseDmg
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.name = name
    self.weapons = weapons
    self.items = items
    self.isAlive = isAlive
    self.previousRoom = previousRoom
    self.coords = (0, 0)

  def Move(self, direction):
    if direction not in self.room.exits:
      print("Cannot Move In That Direction!")
      return
    newRoomName = self.room.exits[direction]
    self.previousRoom = self.room.name
    print("Moving to", newRoomName)
    world[newRoomName] = newRoomName
    self.room = world[newRoomName]

class Room():
  def __init__(self, name, description, exits, hasWeapon, weapon, hasItem, item, hasEnemy, enemy, isFirstVisit, coords):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.exits = exits
    self.hasWeapon = hasWeapon
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.hasItem = hasItem
    self.item = item
    self.hasEnemy = hasEnemy
    self.enemy = enemy
    self.isFirstVisit = isFirstVisit
    self.coords = coords

world = {}
rooms = np.empty((11,11), object)

rooms[5][5] = Room(
  "room1",
  "",
  {"E": "room2"},
  False,
  None,
  False,
  None,
  False,
  None,
  True,
  (5, 5)
)
rooms[5][6] = Room(
  "room2",
  "",
  {"W": "room1"},
  False,
  None,
  False,
  None,
  False,
  None,
  True,
  (5, 5)
)

counter = 1

world["room1"] = rooms[3][3]
world["room2"] = rooms[3][4]

player = Player(10, 10, 5, 5, "Jedidiah", [], [], True, world["room1"].coords, world["room1"].coords)
```

What I am trying to do is make a movement system in python using a 2d array and dictionaries (as per the project requirements), but it keeps giving me an error saying that "str object has no attribute 'coords'":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
    player = Player(10, 10, 5, 5, "Ethan", [], [], True, world["room1"].coords, world["room1"].coords)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

I have no idea why this is happening, but I'm sure it is a simple solution. I am new to programming, so please make the answers as simple as possible. All help is appreciated.

Comment: np.empty makes an empty array, world["room1"] is set to that at index rooms[3][3]. Since it's empty, you cannot use .coords on it. did you mean to make world["room1"] and world["room2"] be the rooms that you made before? They are set at different indicies.

Comment: You need `world["room1"] = rooms[5][5]` and `world["room2"] = rooms[5][6]`

Comment: omg i'm such an idiot. thank you so much. I feel really dumb now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.empty` with object dtype makes an array with `None` elements:

```
In [184]: rooms = np.empty((2,2), object)
In [185]: rooms
Out[185]: 
array([[None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

I see you have a set a couple of elements of `rooms` [5,5] and [5,6] to `Room` objects, and assigned a couple of other elements to the `world` dict (3,3) (3,4).  These elements are still `None`.

Looks like all those 'unset' coordinates are giving you problems.  Either be more careful about the indexing, or add some safeguards to correctly handle `None` elements.